# Dúvida com View Tipada?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PostGetModel.Models;

namespace PostGetModel.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var pessoa = new Pessoa
                {
                    PessoaId = 1,
                    Nome = "teste teste",
                    twitter = "@teste"

                };

            return View(pessoa);
        }

    }
}
```

no Index :

O código não completa nesta parte onde adiciono o :PostGetModel o que poderia está errado?

```
@Model PostGetModel.Models.Pessoa;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>model.PessoaId</p>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O sistema levanta alguma exceção? Qual é o nome da sua view?

Comment: O nome da view é index

Comment: O problema está nesta parte :


@Model PostGetModel.Models.Pessoa


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>model.PessoaId</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItaSouza,

Nesta parte do código

```
<p>model.PessoaId</p>
```

Para acessar o seu model, você precisaria fazer do seguinte modo:

```
<p>@Model.PessoaId</p>
```

Isto se dá porque ao colocar um elemento sem o "@" dentro de uma tag HTML, o Razor interpretará este como um código HTML, e não um código C#.

Se o nome da View for index, como você indicou, é necessário que esta tenha o mesmo nome de sua Action, no caso, Index, dentro da pasta Home. Contudo, se a exceção levantada é na View, então você está conseguindo acessar a página com sucesso.

Como indicado também por Leandro, a diretiva que indica qual é o ViewModel de sua view deve ser sempre minuscula, enquanto que para acessar o atributo Model de sua view, esta deve ser sempre em maiúscula.

Comment: Amigo Vinícius, sua dica foi importante para mim que estou começando no MVC, mais o problema esta em :
@Model PostGetModel.Models.Pessoa não está reconhecendo isso.

Comment: Entendo. Pode postar a exceção?

Comment: Veja a imagem!!  agradeço!!

Comment: A diretiva `@model`que informa o tipo usado pelo Model deve ser sempre em minúscula, no caso a usada na primeira linha da sua View

Comment: Agradeço a todos! Vinícius, você acertou quanto falou sobre :@model PostGetModel.Models.Pessoa , está como @Model e por isso não reconhecia, mais agora eu já entendo melhor sobre View Tipada , ViewBag, ViewData